# Vaadin Flow Grid. How get the data/rows from grid

Tags: vaadin10, vaadin-flow

i use Grid with DataProvider and lazy loading to load the data into the grid.

How can i get the data from grid after the data was loaded? I mean, i need get a data from grid that already have a data.

i need something like `grid.get....`

thx.

Answer (score 0):

I would use grid.getDataCommunicator().fetchFromProvider(..) which returns stream of items  method for this, see API spec here: https://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin/vaadin-core/10.0.2/com/vaadin/flow/data/provider/DataCommunicator.html#fetchFromProvider-int-int-

Comment: thanks, bu this method is protected, i can not do this grid.getDataCommunicator().fetchFromProvider(1,1); can you give me a full example please?

Answer (score 0):

Since Vaadin 17, you can use `DataView` API to get currently shown item/items in the `Grid`:

```
  GridDataView<Person> dataView = grid.getGenericDataView();
  Person item = dataView.getItem(42);
  // or get all shown items
  dataView.getItems().forEach(item -> export(item));
```

Here is an example how to collect the data for export: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/binding-data/data-provider/#accessing-currently-shown-items